# Как реализовать автоматическое добавление из БД вариантов в форму ?

Tags: html, php, javascript, sql

Допустим у нас система "Школьный журнал".

В БД есть таблица "Пользователи" с двумя столбцами: "имя" и "тип". Типов три: учитель, ученик, родитель. И есть две формы  `<select>`, в первой выбираем тип пользователя, там изначально три вышеуказанных варианта, во второй же - данные из столбца "имя" всех записей таблицы "Пользователи". Когда в первой форме мы выбираем, допустим, тип "учитель" - во второй форме отображаются только записи из столбца "имя", у которых соответствующий "тип".

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Что реализовать-то? Загрузку на страницу необходимой информации? AJAX.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы форма свои варианты брала из БД? И в зависимости от того, что введено в другую форму

Comment: @tanias08, AJAX! а логику придумать не сложно

Comment: Я не спрашиваю, сложно это или легко. Если я задала вопрос, значит я пыталась и придумать, и найти решение, но не смогла и прошу помощи, а не оценки сложности задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вешаете обработчик события `change` на нужный элемент `select`
- Отправляете AJAX с выбранным значением
- Принимаете данные и подставляете в другие элементы `select`

Ваш вопрос очень абстрактен и сильно зависит от того на чем и как реализовано Ваше приложение, тк идёт взаимодействие с сервером. Разбейте его на пункты, что-то вроде:

- как отследить когда пользователь что-то выбрал в выпадающем списке?
- как получить пункт который он выбрал?
- как отправить данные на сервер при помощи AJAX?
- у меня есть таблица SQL с такими-то полями, и есть значние поля ХХХ как мне выбрать YYY?
- как получить данные от сервера при помощи AJAX?
- как подставить нужные значения в select или создать новый select?

и что из этого будет не ясно - спрашивайте тут ;) Успехов!

Comment: непонятно больше всего, как подставить нужные значения в select